# Gridview usercontrol with delete row functionality doesn't update my gridview after delete

Tags: asp.net, gridview, crud

I have a gridview usercontrol with CRUD functionality. I have an OnRowDeleting event and an RowCommand event that checks if my 'Delete' button is clicked.

OnRowDeleting:

```
protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        grd.EditIndex = -1;
        pnlSelected.Visible = false;
        btnSave.Visible = false;
        btnInsert.Visible = false;
        grd.DataBind();
    }
```

RowCommand:

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;    // the button
            GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)lnkBtn.Parent.Parent;  // the row
            GridView myGrid = (GridView)sender; // the gridview

            string item = (string)myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            DataController.DeleteByPrimKey(item);
        }
    }
```

In my webform I fill up the datasource of my usercontrol. The problem now is when I want to delete a record.

```
ucShowHouseList.DataSource = myDataSource;
```

If I delete a record in my gridview, the gridview doesn't show the change. If I refresh the page the record is deleted.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I think my problem is that the datasource in the usercontrol doesn't get updated after a delete. So in the Page_Load of my webform I fill up the datasource of my usercontrol:

`ucShowHouseList.DataSource = myDataSource;`

On row deleting in my usercontrol I do now:

```
grd.DataSource = DataSource;
grd.DataBind();
```

DataSource is an IENumerable property in my usercontrol that I fill up on page_load in my webform.

```
public IEnumerable DataSource;
```

This returns a collection of items and isn't updated when I delete a row because my page isn't reloaded so the collection can't be updated.

How to solve that?

Comment: Side-note: instead of `lnkBtn.Parent.Parent` use `lnkBtn.NamingContainer` to get the `GridViewRow`. According to your issue, do you `DataBind` the `GridView` after you've changed the `DataSource`?

Comment: ok nevermind I solved my problem by refilling my datasource and then rebinding it. My problem is solved now

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your Gridview Binding function after `grd_RowDeleting` not `grd.DataBind();`
`Gridview.DataBind` need a data source to bind . [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)